# Sql developer STORED PROCEDURE FOR INSERT STATEMENT WITH AUTO INCREMENT ID

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert, auto-increment, unique-constraint

I have a problem when I am trying to run stored procedure for insert statment. I got error: unique constraint violated and I don't understand why because I set my primary key to be sequence or autoincrement. 
This is my stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SACUVAJCUSTOMERDETAILNADA 
(
ID_ OUT CUSTOMERDETAILNADA.ID%TYPE,
FIRSTNAME_ IN CUSTOMERDETAILNADA.FIRSTNAME%TYPE
,LASTNAME_ IN CUSTOMERDETAILNADA.LASTNAME%TYPE
,MAIDENNAME_ IN CUSTOMERDETAILNADA.MAIDENNAME%TYPE
 MOTHERSMAIDENNAME_ IN CUSTOMERDETAILNADA.MOTHERSMAIDENNAME%TYPE
)AS
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO CUSTOMERDETAILNADA(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,MAIDENNAME,MOTHERSMAIDENNAME)
 VALUES(FIRSTNAME_,LASTNAME_,MAIDENNAME_,MOTHERSMAIDENNAME_)
RETURNING CUSTOMERDETAILNADA.ID INTO ID_;
END SACUVAJCUSTOMERDETAILNADA;

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!
```

Comment: What are the constraints on CUSTOMERDETAILNADA?

Comment: Constraints that only primary key have to be unique. I solved my problem! I see that in sequence folder sql developer start increment at 1 and I have 10 object in CUSTOMERDETAILNADA,so when I delete all they work! 
Thank's for reply!

Comment: No problem, glad you could figure out the problem!